# Trouble Simplifying an Integral in “Irresistible Integrals”

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

On page $251$ in George Boros’ *Irresistible Integrals*, I saw the following equality due to the Cauchy-Schlömilch transformation when letting $f(x)=1/(1+x)^r$ with $r>1/2$.

$$\int_0^{\infty}(1+(cx-a/x)^2)^{-r}dx=\frac{1}{c}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{du}{(1+u^2)^r}$$

Which makes sense to me. However, he said to let $c=a$ and $a=\sqrt{2(a+1)}$ to get on the left side

$$[2(a+1)]^r\int_0^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{x^2}{x^4+2ax^2+1}\Bigr)^rdx$$

And for the right side, it evaluates to

$$\frac{\sqrt{2(a+1)}}{2}B(r-1/2, 1/2)$$

However I think the right side is a mistake, and I think it evaluates to

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2(a+1)}}B(r-1/2, 1/2)$$

Where $B(x, y)$ is the Beta function. I want to know if I’m correct in this regard. Also, I don’t know why the left side evaluates to what it is in the book.

I tried to do turn $\int_0^{\infty}(1+(cx-a/x)^2)^{-r}dx$ into $[2(a+1)]^r\int_0^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{x^2}{x^4+2ax^2+1}\Bigr)^rdx$ myself by expanding $(cx-1/x)^2+1$ and advancing top and bottom inside of the parentheses by $x^2$, but I don’t get anywhere. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Most likely there is a typo in the book and you're right with that result. I'm not sure what integral you tried to do by yourself, but if you're after the last one, you can start by writting the integral as $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+1/x^2+2a)^r}dx$, let $x\to \frac{1}{x}$ and add both integrals up to get $\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+1/x^2+2a)^r}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx$, then think what substitution to use to get rid of both $x^2+1/x^2$ and that outer term.

Comment: I’ll edit it to be more specific, my bad. I tried to turn $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+(cx-a/x)^2)^r}$ into $[2(a+1)]^r\int_0^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{x^2}{x^4+2ax^2+1}\Bigr)^rdx$. To clarify, is that what you mean by ‘the last one’? Thanks for the input.

Comment: Well, after you let $c=a$ there is $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+a^2(x-1/x)^2)^r}dx$, and after setting $a=\sqrt{2(b+1)}$ you should arrive with some algebra at $[2(b+1)]^r\int_0^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{x^2}{x^4+2bx^2+1}\Bigr)^rdx$.//
For "the last one" I just took $\int_0^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{x^2}{x^4+2ax^2+1}\Bigr)^rdx$ and divided the numerator and the denominator by $x^2$ to get $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+1/x^2+2a)^r}dx$.

Comment: Ah, understood. Thank you.

Comment: In fact, from doing what you said, I derived the equality $[2(a+1)]^r\int_0^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{x^2}{x^4+2ax^2+1}\Bigr)^rdx=\sqrt{2(a+1)}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^r}$. It’s just that it’s written in the book that one should work with each side individually, which is clearly not how this all ended up working out, so I guess that’s the mistake. Thank you for the help.